# Describe the center of the group of all homeomorphism on R?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $H(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all strictly increasing homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $H(\mathbb{R})$ is a group under composition. What is the center of this group?

Comment: Why is the inverse of one such increasing?

Comment: Is strictly monotonic a group?

Comment: @par But the inverse of a strictly increasing function **is** strictly increasing! For instance, the inverse of $(x\mapsto ax+b)$ is $\left(x\mapsto \frac1a x-\frac ba\right)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Jeez, that will teach me not to believe anything without thinking about it. Thanks.

Comment: ...and that will teach me to think about things.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich One gets easily confused with convex *increasing* functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ (all three hypothesis are somehow necessary): their inverse is concave and increasing. That will teach me etcetera...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think it's probably safest to conclude just that one gets easily confused...

Answer (score 9):

The center is trivial. Say $f$ is not the identity. Choose $a$ with $f(a)\ne a$. There certainly exists $g$ with $g(f(a))\ne f(a)$ and $g(a)=a$; hence $f(g(a))\ne g(f(a))$.

Comment: Much more concise than my answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Let $z\in H(\mathbb{R})$ be in the center. Then $z^{-1}$ is in the center. That is, $$z^{-1}(f(x))=f(z^{-1}(x))\text{ for all }f\in H(\mathbb{R}).$$
For fixed $c>0$, take $f=cz$ to get $$z^{-1}(cz(x))=cz(z^{-1}(x))=cx\implies cz(x)=z(cx).$$ That is, $z$ is a line through the origin. Denote its slope by $a$. Since $z$ is in the center, it follows that $$af(x)=f(ax)\text{ for all }f\in H(\mathbb{R}).$$ This implies that $a=1$ since otherwise all homeomorphisms are homogeneous ($x\mapsto x^3$ is a nonhomogeneous homeomorphism). Therefore, **the center is trivial**.